# Good source for a complete guide to Linux (for the layman)

Tags: linux, architecture

I started following the Linux From Scratch book and I really enjoy everything I'm learning (extensive error messages are great for learning * grin *). However, I'm still looking for a rundown of the actual Linux architecture that clearly explains the different root folders, how mounting to a file works and how everything just ties together.

I know this is a whole lot of info, but I'm sure there's a source out there for the semi-knowledged (if not, I'm a first year computer engineer so it doesn't have to be super basic).

Comment: Look at Linux Documentation Project http://tldp.org/

Comment: I like it, but I was looking for something more aggregated. Picture "Linux for Dummies" but and advanced version that doesn't just tell you how to install a distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete guide to Linux is something of an oxymoron, almost a one-liner. If you're looking for a "complete" guide, then you have not yet grokked the Tao of Linux.

You can't have a complete guide to something that exists concurrently in so many separate flavors that each do things differently, each constantly on the move. The world of Linux is an ever-changing ecosystem.

There are lots of different places to go for pieces of the puzzle — snippets of design philosophy, architecture of individual pieces. But nothing can give you a "complete" picture.

One resource I'd recommend to you to help you on your journey is Eric S. Raymond's "[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/)".

Answer (score 1):

Its not a 'book' but this is the best, most comprehensive guide to the [linux file system hierachy](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/) i've seen so far. With exception with one or two varients, this is supposed to be fairly standardised. tldp.org has quite a few other interesting guides to linux internals.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a book on OS architecture, Modern Operating Systems by Tanenbaum or the Dinosaur Book (Operating System Concepts) by Galvin and Silberschatz are both popular, although I only own the latter. They don't necessarily focus on Linux specifically, but most Unix-like systems are similar to some degree.

I haven't found any complete online guide to Linux, since different distributions frequently do things slightly differently and the websites I've seen tend to get out of date quickly. I'd appreciate such a guide as well.

Comment: I know what you mean. Right now my knowledge all comes from either trial and error, or reading some user's post on an issue they have.